# distorting live paint objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am a hobbyist graphic designer, looking to recreate part of this image, specifically the top half with the sun: [image: From the sun up]

Right now, I made a crude copy using line segments, and filled them in with live paint bucket. However, I liked the look of the waves at the top, and was wondering how to get those with my image. So if anyone has any ways to distort the lines without ruining the circle, that would help a bunch.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take a different approach. Live Paint is fun, but it has some limitations.

Instead, I'd draw the lines with the Curvature Tool, clean up and make the individual pieces with the Shape Builder Tool.

Example

[image]

Then fill each piece with the desired colour

[image]

Comment: Wow, this helps a bunch, looks like I just needed a little paradigm shift. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Once doesn't "distort lines without ruining the circle". 
You draw the lines then clip them to the circle.

This is merely a collection of single paths.

The **Shape Builder Tool** is used to remove portions, by holding down <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> while dragging.

Then the **Live Paint Bucket Tool** is used to fill the remaining shapes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question:

[image]

Live Paint allows editing the shape borders and the paint follows as long as the paint is not expanded. After expanding you must edit the shapes separately.

In the left there's a non-expanded Live Paint result

In the middle a couple of new anchors are inserted to a borderline and the anchors are dragged a little off with the direct selection tool

In the right the anchors are made smooth with the anchor point conversion tool.

BTW Check from the Illustrator documentation (by Adobe) how to draw and edit curved paths. I guess most of us would draw curved paths from the start for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is another great way of doing this.